# Create Dynamic pages in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-sites, dynamic-pages

I need to integrate the functionality of creating dynamic pages (like google sites) to my regular asp.net mvc(C#) application. I like to write my own code with database.

Any suggestions or reference for this?

Comment: As long as your dynamic site supports javascript you could use restful web services and JSON results to retrieve your data with jQuery and Ajax. [Here's a link on asynchronous data loading using jQuery and json results that may help you here.](http://oddiandeveloper.blogspot.com/2008/11/asynchronous-data-loading-in-aspnet-mvc.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to read this article by [Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/), [Scripting ASP.NET MVC Views Stored In The Database](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/22/scripted-db-views.aspx).